# チャットはいつ使えるようになりますか?

Tags: サポート, 完了, チャット

[チャットルーム一覧](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)でstack overflowで検索してもSO日本語版がでてきません。

[image: チャットでstack overflowを検索]

Comment: まだ設定していないが、できるはずです。確認してみます。

Answer (score 2):

チャットは使えますが、2つの注意点があります。

1. チャットの翻訳は一切していない、英語のままになる
2. チャットをオンにすると、ネットワーク全体が見つかることができる

現在SO日本語版は半分秘密です。サイトを作るとは発表していますが、それ以上は伝えていないです。

技術面では問題はありませんが、上記の2点だけがあります。

Comment: なるほど。公開ベータに入るまでは、チャットはオフにしておきたい、ということで合っていますか? メイン・メタ・チャットの三つ組をプライベートベータで試せた方がベターだと思います。英語のままのチャットがどんなuxになるかも含めて。